# Embedded C programming: Clearing LCD properly

Tags: c, embedded

I am trying to write the code for an embedded board (RX63N)in which I want to use the LCD along with the on board switches for the following functionality:
On pressing the switch the program should "pause" or "unpause" depending on the previous state and the LCD should  display "paused" when it is paused. On unpausing, the LCD should display the custom graphics at the position defined by x and y. It is displayed using the function Set_LCD_Char(N) where N is defined as a custom graphic from a bitmap image. But I will need to clear the LCD before making any changes and that is where I am struggling. On using lcd_clear() function anywhere in the while keeps the LCD blank (or almost blank i.e. the text and graphics are so faint that they are as good as absent) Can someone please help me? heres the code:

```
while (1)
{
//  lcd_clear();
if(g_sw3_press == true){         //detect switch press
        pause_flag = !pause_flag;
        g_sw3_press = false;    //reset switch

    }

    if (pause_flag){
        RESET_ALL_LEDS();
        jet_x = 0;
        jet_y = 0;
         Set_Font_Bitmap();   //changes from text mode to bitmap
         Set_LCD_Pos(jet_x,jet_y);
         Set_LCD_Char(3);

    }
    else if(!(pause_flag)){ 
        ALL_RED_LEDS_ON();
         Set_Font_8_by_8();         
        lcd_display(LCD_LINE1, "    PAUSED   ");
    }   

}
```

Comment: We don't know what your platform is and we don't know how any of those functions are implemented. It's like you have placed us in the middle of the desert (with a blind fold) and am asking us to help you find the way home. So it is unlikely that anyone would know what you are talking about. Please review the help on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Having said that, it looks like the code does not actually pause. So probably you need to actually pause so that `lcd_clear` is not called again immediately after you have done your display updates. That is, where is the code that blocks on the switch input?

Comment: "pause" or "unpause" are just two states that I am referring to, so I don't need to actually pause, I need to do polling over and over again and display the text if paused and graphics if unpaused.

Comment: Then you should probably only call `lcd_clear` when the state changes. In fact, you should only draw to the lcd when the state changes. That is, do nothing if the state is the same.

Comment: the functions dealing with lcd are predefined and are just supposed to work out of the box. I am basically trying to figure out its correct usage. I know this is sloppy and messed p but hope this makes sense.

Comment: @AlanAu can you elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's generally not a good idea to do a busy polling loop as you are doing. But I can't recommend any concrete alternatives as platform and OS (if any) have not been provided (perhaps your platform has no support for events).

Anyway, not sure if this is the answer you need. But since you ask for an example and I can't effectively put code into the comments, below is what I mean. The problem is that you are continuously writing and clearing the LCD. So in effect the two operations are competing with each other. So one way to solve this is to only update the LCD when the state changes.

```
while (1)
{
    if(g_sw3_press == true){         //detect switch press
        pause_flag = !pause_flag;
        g_sw3_press = false;    //reset switch
    } else {
        /* No state change - nothing to do. Poll again. */
        continue;
    }

    lcd_clear(); 
    if (pause_flag){
        RESET_ALL_LEDS();
        jet_x = 0;
        jet_y = 0;
         Set_Font_Bitmap();   //changes from text mode to bitmap
         Set_LCD_Pos(jet_x,jet_y);
         Set_LCD_Char(3);

    } else { 
        ALL_RED_LEDS_ON();
         Set_Font_8_by_8();         
        lcd_display(LCD_LINE1, "    PAUSED   ");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Taught me a lot!